# Determine Color Based on Percentage Gradient

Tags: html, css, angular

I am looking for a way to determine a solid color based on a percentage of a gradient. Basically like the image below

[image: Gradient Color Scale]

I have used CSS to get the gradient but I cannot figure out how I can just pick a solid color from that gradient. This is the CSS for the gradient:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b050 20%, #4ac148 40%, #74d13e, #9de031, #c6ee21, #dbe508, #eedb00, #ffd000, #ffad00, #ff8700, #ff5b00, #ff0000);
```

Worst case, I could just go through and assign RGB values from 0-100 on that gradient and use that. However, I can't help but think there has to be a better programmatic way to solve this.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: use:
 background-color:hsl(perc,100%,50%);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to calculate the intermediate color between 2 colors is so easy as use

```
color1=rgb(ar,ag,ab)
color2=rgb(br,bg,bb)
color=rgb(ar+factor*(br-ar),ag+factor*(bg-ag),ab+factor*(bb-ab))
```

Well, to make easer calculate the factor, we can create a series of divs. So imagine you has a gradient like

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#ff0000,#00ffff);
```

I go to create an array of colors

```
colors2:any[]=[
 {color:"#ff0000",porc:0},
 {color:"#ff0000",porc:0},
 {color:"#00ffff",porc:100},
]
```

See that I repeat the first element with porc:0

And transform adding r,g,b properties

```
this.colors2.forEach(c=>{
  c.r=parseInt(c.color.substr(1,2),16)
  c.g=parseInt(c.color.substr(3,2),16)
  c.b=parseInt(c.color.substr(5),16)
})
```

So I can make a *ngFor

```
<div class="col" (mousemove)="mouseMove($event,colors2[i],colors2[i+1])" 
   *ngFor="let color of colors2|slice:0:(colors2.length-1);let i=index"
  [style.background-image]="'linear-gradient(to right,'+colors2[i].color+','+colors2[i+1].color+')'"
  [style.width]="(colors2[i+1].porc-colors2[i].porc)+'%'">
</div>
```

where

```
.col
{
  height:2rem;
  display:inline-block
}
```

Where the function mouseMove calculate the intermediate color

```
  mouseMove(e,color1,color2)
  {
    this.margin=e.clientX-14
    const rect=e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const alfa=(e.clientX - rect.left)/rect.width
    const r=Math.floor(color1.r+alfa*(color2.r-color1.r)).toString(16)
    const g=Math.floor(color1.g+alfa*(color2.g-color1.g)).toString(16)
    const b=Math.floor(color1.b+alfa*(color2.b-color1.b)).toString(16)
    const color=('00'+r).slice(-2)+('00'+g).slice(-2)+('00'+b).slice(-2)
    this.result="#"+color
  }
```

in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kazuhe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) you can see three gradients. Each gradient has two horizontal divs, one with the div with a gradient using css, and bellow the "simulate" div compouse with severals divs. If you move the mouse over this last, you see the color

Comment: Solved! Thank you for your answer. Especially, the stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to make the gradient VERY big and you adjust the `background-position` to have one color or at least approximate it:

```css
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00b050 20%, #4ac148 40%, #74d13e, #9de031, #c6ee21, #dbe508, #eedb00, #ffd000, #ffad00, #ff8700, #ff5b00, #ff0000);
  background-size:10000% 100%;
  border:10px solid;
  width:50px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-position:20% 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-position:40% 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-position:50% 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-position:60% 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-position:70% 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-position:80% 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-position:100% 0"></div>
```